# При клике на второй трек что-бы первый останавливался

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Привет.

Использую [вот этот плеер](https://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly). Столкнулся с проблемой: когда нажимаешь на первый трек то все ок, но при нажатии на второй, первый не останавливается и играет уже два :(

Помогите решить, не знаю, что добавить в код. Имею такой код:

```js
$(function() {
  $('audio').audioPlayer({
    classPrefix: 'audioplayer',
    strPlay: 'Play',
    strPause: 'Pause',
    strVolume: 'Volume'
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #c3d5d3;
  padding: 3.75em 1.875em;
  /* 60 30 */
}

strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 30em;
  /* 480 */
  height: 8.75em;
  /* 140 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -4.375em 0 0 -15em;
  /* 70 240 */
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.688em;
  /* 27 */
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.741em;
  /* 20 */
}

h1,
h1 a,
#copyright,
#copyright a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1);
}

h1 a,
#copyright a {
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: text-shadow .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: text-shadow .25s ease;
  -o-transition: text-shadow .25s ease;
  transition: text-shadow .25s ease;
}

h1 a:hover,
h1 a:focus,
#copyright a:hover,
#copyright a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, .3);
}

h1 em {
  font-family: Baskerville, serif;
}

#copyright {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  /* 14 */
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.429em;
  /* 20 */
}

#copyright a {
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*
   PLAYER
  */

.audioplayer {
  height: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
}


/* mini mode (fallback) */

.audioplayer-mini {
  width: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* player elements: play/pause and volume buttons, played/duration timers, progress bar of loaded/played */

.audioplayer>div {
  position: absolute;
}


/* play/pause button */

.audioplayer-playpause {
  width: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.audioplayer:not(.audioplayer-mini) .audioplayer-playpause {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-right-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.audioplayer-mini .audioplayer-playpause {
  width: 100%;
}

.audioplayer-playpause:hover,
.audioplayer-playpause:focus {
  background-color: #222;
}

.audioplayer-playpause a {
  display: block;
}

.audioplayer-stopped .audioplayer-playpause a {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0.5em solid transparent;
  /* 8 */
  border-right: none;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -0.5em 0 0 -0.25em;
  /* 8 4 */
}

.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a {
  width: 0.75em;
  /* 12 */
  height: 0.75em;
  /* 12 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -0.375em 0 0 -0.375em;
  /* 6 */
}

.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a:before,
.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a:after {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a:before {
  left: 0;
}

.audioplayer-playing .audioplayer-playpause a:after {
  right: 0;
}


/* timers */

.audioplayer-time {
  width: 4.375em;
  /* 70 */
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 2.375em;
  /* 38 */
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}

.audioplayer-time-current {
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  border-left-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .25);
  left: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
}

.audioplayer-time-duration {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-right-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1);
  right: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
}

.audioplayer-novolume .audioplayer-time-duration {
  border-right: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/* progress bar of loaded/played */

.audioplayer-bar {
  height: 0.875em;
  /* 14 */
  background-color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  right: 6.875em;
  /* 110 */
  left: 6.875em;
  /* 110 */
  margin-top: -0.438em;
  /* 7 */
}

.audioplayer-novolume .audioplayer-bar {
  right: 4.375em;
  /* 70 */
}

.audioplayer-bar div {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.audioplayer-bar-loaded {
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 1;
}

.audioplayer-bar-played {
  background: #007fd1;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* volume button */

.audioplayer-volume {
  width: 2.5em;
  /* 40 */
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  border-left-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .25);
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.audioplayer-volume:hover,
.audioplayer-volume:focus {
  background-color: #222;
}

.audioplayer-volume-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.audioplayer-volume-button a {
  width: 0.313em;
  /* 5 */
  height: 0.375em;
  /* 6 */
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40%;
  left: 35%;
}

.audioplayer-volume-button a:before,
.audioplayer-volume-button a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.audioplayer-volume-button a:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0.5em solid transparent;
  /* 8 */
  border-left: none;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  right: -0.25em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  /* 8 */
}

.audioplayer:not(.audioplayer-muted) .audioplayer-volume-button a:after {
  /* "volume" icon by Nicolas Gallagher, http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons */
  width: 0.313em;
  /* 5 */
  height: 0.313em;
  /* 5 */
  border: 0.25em double #fff;
  /* 4 */
  border-width: 0.25em 0.25em 0 0;
  /* 4 */
  left: 0.563em;
  /* 9 */
  top: -0.063em;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0.938em 0 0;
  /* 15 */
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0.938em 0 0;
  /* 15 */
  border-radius: 0 0.938em 0 0;
  /* 15 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  transform: rotate( 45deg);
}


/* volume dropdown */

.audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  height: 6.25em;
  /* 100 */
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: -1px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: #333;
}

.audioplayer-volume:not(:hover) .audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  opacity: 0;
}

.audioplayer-volume:hover .audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust>div {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 30% auto 0;
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust div div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #007fd1;
}

.audioplayer-novolume .audioplayer-volume {
  display: none;
}


/* CSS3 decorations */

body {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* 300 */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, 5);
  /* 300 */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 18.75em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* 300 */
}

.audioplayer {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .15), 0 0 1.25em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* 20 */
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .15), 0 0 1.25em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* 20 */
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .15), 0 0 1.25em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* 20 */
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15), 2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15), 2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15), 2px -2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.audioplayer-bar,
.audioplayer-volume-adjust>div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5), 1px 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5), 1px 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5), 1px 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust div div,
.audioplayer-bar-played {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.audioplayer-playpause,
.audioplayer-volume a {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 0 #000);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 0 #000);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 0 #000);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 0 #000);
  filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 0 #000);
}

.audioplayer,
.audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from( #444), to( #222));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #444, #222);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #444, #222);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient( top, #444, #222);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( top, #444, #222);
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #444, #222);
}

.audioplayer-bar-played {
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, from( #007fd1), to( #c600ff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( left, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient( left, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( left, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: linear-gradient( to right, #007fd1, #c600ff);
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust div div {
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, from( #007fd1), to( #c600ff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( bottom, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( bottom, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient( bottom, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( bottom, #007fd1, #c600ff);
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #007fd1, #c600ff);
}

.audioplayer-bar,
.audioplayer-bar div,
.audioplayer-volume-adjust div {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.audioplayer {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.audioplayer-volume-adjust {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

.audioplayer *,
.audioplayer *:before,
.audioplayer *:after {
  -webkit-transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
  -o-transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
  transition: color .25s ease, background-color .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
}


/* responsiveness */

@media only screen and ( max-width: 32.5em)
/* 520 */

{
  body {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 9.375em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
    /* 150 */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 9.375em rgba( 0, 0, 0, 5);
    /* 150 */
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 9.375em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5);
    /* 150 */
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://osvaldas.info/examples/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly/audioplayer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://osvaldas.info/examples/main.css">

<audio controls class="portfolio__audio">
  <source src="sound/track1 - Lubov opasnaya.mp3">
</audio>
<audio controls class="portfolio__audio">
  <source src="sound/track2 - This world (cover Selah Sue).mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот **JS**  код. Здесь смысл такой: если началось воспроизведение, то скрипт ищет все объекты `<audio>` в документе, кроме того, в котором началось воспроизведение, ставит их на паузу и время проигрывателя в 0.

`$('audio').bind('playing', function() {
    $.each($('audio').not($(this)), function () {
        $(this)[0].pause();
        $(this)[0].currentTime = 0.0;
    })
});`